# Gets data from the Firestore Database along with the query

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I only need to download data from the Firestore Database that is equal to something. It crashes me an error:

```
Cannot read property 'onSnapshot' of undefined
```

How can I get data from Firestore and create a query?

My code:

```
const messages = this.firestore.collection('chat', ref => {
    ref.where('receiver_id', '==', employee.user.id);
    }).valueChanges().subscribe((message) => {
        console.log(message);
    });
```

My Firestore Database:

[image: My Firestore Database]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not returning anything from within the callback, which means that AngularFire ends up trying to call `onSnapshot` on `undefined`.

It should be either:

```
const messages = this.firestore.collection('chat', ref => {
    return ref.where('receiver_id', '==', employee.user.id);
}).valueChanges().subscribe((message) => {
    console.log(message);
});
```

Or more commonly written as:

```
const messages = this.firestore.collection('chat', ref => ref.where('receiver_id', '==', employee.user.id))
.valueChanges().subscribe((message) => {
    console.log(message);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The messages will not be assigned to `const messages` in your code.
You should put your logic inside the subscribe.

```
let messages;
this.firestore.collection('chat', ref => {
    return ref.where('receiver_id', '==', employee.user.id);
})
.valueChanges()
.subscribe((message) => {
    console.log(message);
    messages = message;
});
```

Also, you will actually need to extract the data() from your `message` response. Something like `message.docs.map(doc => doc.data());`.

Comment: As you can see on @Frank's answer, your callback does not return anything

Answer (score 0):

```js
getData() {
  var array = []
  return this.firestore.collection('chat', ref =>
      ref.where('receiver_id', '==', this.employee.user.id)).snapshotChanges()
    .subscribe(res => {
      array = res.map(msg => {
        return {
          id: msg.payload.doc.id,
          ...msg.payload.doc.data() as {}
        }
      })
    })
}
```